# Qt and C++ Tab Tree generator

Tags: c++, qt

I am using Qt + C++ to create a Tab tree as it is showed in the following image:

[image: Qt Tab Tree]

I'd like to create a class that inherit from QWidget in the following way:

```
    class Tab: public QWidget
    {
        public:          
            explicit Tab(QWidget * parentTabWidget, const QString &label, QWidget *parent = nullptr ): QWidget(parent)
            {
                auto * tabWidget = new QTabWidget();
                auto * tabLayout = new QVBoxLayout();
                tabWidget->addTab(this, label);
                if (!parentTabWidget->layout()) 
                { 
                   parentTabWidget->setLayout(tabLayout); 
                }
                parentTabWidget->layout()->addWidget(tabWidget);
                
            }
        private:
            QString mLabel;

   };
```

with the following implementation:

```
QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
widget->setLayout(layout);

Tab * tab1 = new Tab(widget, "Tab1");
Tab * subTab1 = new Tab(tab1, "subTab1");  // when I add this line it fails. After I add this line when I run the application it closes.
```

Comment: Is there any error message ?

Comment: the application closes immediately after I add  this line: Tab * subTab1 = new Tab(tab1, "subTab1");

Comment: `parentTabWidget->layout()` Does this return a nullptr? That would be my guess. A widget does not come with a layout unless you add it.

Comment: Sorry I have edited it adding     QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
    widget->setLayout(layout);

Comment: That is not helping `tab1`. Remember when you call `Tab * subTab1 = new Tab(tab1, "subTab1");` it executes `tab1->layout()->addWidget(subTab1);` and `tab1` has no layout created.

Comment: @sergiocampo that is pointless, each level needs a layout, you're just creating it for the top layer.

Comment: @drescherjm you were right. I have added if (!parentTabWidget->layout()) {
 parentTabWidget->setLayout(tabLayout);  } and now it works. thank you!

Comment: @musicamante you were right as well thank you!